# When is an instance of the main activity disposed in Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

According to the Xamarin documentation:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/

the activities have a described life cycle. Moreover, the Activity class implements IDisposable. Logically, disposing the main activity is expected to play a role in the life cycle. However, it is not mentioned in the documentation I referred to. What is the role of the Dispose functionality in the life cycle of the main activity? When is an instance disposed?

Comment: `Dispose()` breaks the peer object connection and allows both mono and native Android to reclaim the resources. Read this doc: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/

Comment: I've covered this topic in more depth in one of my other answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863058/xamarin-android-finalizer-not-getting-called-when-leaving-the-activity-to-go-to/28868582#28868582

Comment: Thanks! Now it is far more clear to me.