# When subclassing Xamarin Android.Views.View (or any of its subclasses), do I need to call dispose on objects I created?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, idisposable

If I have a class like this below where I create Drawables and then use them while this button is on the page, is it standard to dispose of all of the ImageDrawable 's when overriding the Dispose method, or should I dispose of them in OnDetachedFromWindow, or is this not needed at all.

1.

```
public class ExampleImageButton : ImageButton
{
    private IList<AnimationDrawable> _animations;

....

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
            foreach(var item in _animations) 
            {
                item.Dispose();
            }
            _animations = null;
        }
        base.Dispose (disposing);
    }
}
```

2.

```
public class ExampleImageButton : ImageButton
{
    private IList<AnimationDrawable> _animations;

....

    protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        foreach(var item in _animations) 
        {
            item.Dispose();
        }
        _animations = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: if my answer doesn't answer the question thoroughly enough, get in contact with me. Happy to chat over Skype etc to explain this in more depth.

Comment: Yeah, you answered my question. I was thinking that they wouldn't get cleaned up and I was assuming number 1 was correct, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. I was slightly unsure because even without disposing of the drawables my code seemed to have been working ok, but I figured it could cause problems in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is standard practice to `Dispose()` child objects within the parents `Dispose()` method. When an object derives from `Java.Lang.Object` it will have a corresponding Java [peer object](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#Object_Cycles).

After you invoke `Dispose()` on a class that subclasses `Java.Lang.Object`, its peer connection is broken (as held by the `IntPtr Handle` property in `Java.Lang.Object`) and is no longer safe to use. `Dispose()` effectively marks an object as a GC candidate in both the Mono and Dalvik virtual machines.

In your example above, the safe way to destroy `IList<AnimationDrawable> _animations` is in example 1. As `Dispose` is guaranteed to be the last method called before an object has it's peer connection broken, you shouldn't dispose child objects in other callbacks (such as `OnDetachedFromWindow`) unless you are **absolutely certain** it won't be used again.

Further reading:

- [Xamarin.Android Garbage Collection](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection)
- [Xamarin Android Finalizer not getting called when leaving the activity to go to another Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863058/xamarin-android-finalizer-not-getting-called-when-leaving-the-activity-to-go-to)
- [System.ArgumentException'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero. Parameter name: jobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571875/system-argumentexceptionjobject-must-not-be-intptr-zero-parameter-name-jobje)